# angular 4 data table show below error on ng serve

Tags: angular, angular5

`angular-4-data-table` shows the following error on `ng serve`:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-4-data-table/src/index.ts
>   Module build failed: Error: \node_modules\angular-4-data-table\src\index.ts is not part of the compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.
>       at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:649:23)

What could the problem be?

I'm using Angular CLI 1.6.2 on Node 6.11.2 on Windows.

Comment: Please be specific what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in Visual code when I deleted some of the redundant files. The error disappeared after:

1. I restarted my Visual Code
2. Did an `npm build` in the terminal window.
3. Now on `ng serve` or on `npm start`, it started with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the node_module and run yarn or npm install

Comment: this should be in the comment section